# Is there a cakephp plugin for unit testing (Used in TDD)?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, cakephp

I actually using Cake Rake testing from web technic but when a tried to do

```
$ cake rake help
```

it gives me

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SimpleReporter' not found in
```

Can you give me several idea for unit testing?

If i have to use a plugin what is the best plugin?

Thank U

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP 2.0 onwards comes with built-in support for PHPUnit and is in fact itself completely unit tested with it. Start here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html

CakePHP versions before 2.0 came with built-in support for SimpleTest instead: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1196/Testing